# fastest AI algorithms for quick chess engine?

Tags: engines

I am looking for some authenticated books , tutorials ,reference sites for quickest algorithms implementation for chess engine creation.

Thank you.
regards
Keshav

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you're looking for the quickest way to code your own chess engine, not the "fastest" algorithm. This is important, because there is no such thing as the "fastest" algorithm; your algorithm might evaluate positions very quickly, but if it doesn't understanding that a queen is mort valued than a pawn, your "fastest" algorithm is useless.

The quickest way to code your own chess engine is to start with something that works.

- http://www.tckerrigan.com/Chess/TSCP/

The TSCP chess engine is simple enough for you to get started.

**PS**: In case you're really looking for the "fastest" algorithm. You'll simply need to code a board generator. Simply take the first move off from the generator. No need to do an alpha-beta search.